# Changed Typescript-Version

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I have a project written in typescript v.1.4 "ECMA6" and i want to use 'async' only because of some calculations needed to be asynchronous.

But after I upgrade my typescript version to 1.8 in Visual Studio 2013, I got big problems with extended classes and I have no idea why?

The exception i get is:

> Class constructor "XYZ"cannot be invoked without 'new'

The classes looks like a extend b, b extend c...

```
class XavObject {
    constructor() { }   
}

class XavWidget extends XavObject {
    constructor(control: JQuery, name?: string, id?: number) {
        super();
    }
}

class Widget_ConstructionKitContainer extends XavWidget {
    constructor(control: JQuery, controlName: string) {
        super(control, controlName, 1); // ---> here throws the exception
    }
}
```

Why this exception occurs and what can i do to resolve it?

**EDIT:**
I try to give more information...

I have a webservice written in C# wich makes the .js-Files from the .ts-Files accessible. Something like "http://localhost:8080/DLLName/XavObject.js"

So that the HTML looks like:

```
 <script src="XavObject.js"></script>
 <script src="XavWidget.js"></script>
 <script src="Widget_ConstructionKitContainer.js"></script>


 <script>
        xavManager.jQuery(document).ready(function () {
          var constructionKitContainer =
          new Widget_ConstructionKitContainer(
          xavManager.jQuery('#ConstructionKitContainer'),
          "ConstructionKitContainer",

          xavManager.jQuery('#regionSelector'),
          xavManager.jQuery('#regionConfigurator'),
          xavManager.jQuery('#regionContainer'),
          xavManager.jQuery('#Preview'),
          xavManager.jQuery('#ThreeDContainer'),
          xavManager.jQuery('#MainThreeD'), 
          xavManager.jQuery('#NavThreeD'),

          [xavManager.jQuery('#ModelTypAuswahl'),
          xavManager.jQuery('#ModelformAuswahl'),
          xavManager.jQuery('#WandArtikelAuswahl'),
          xavManager.jQuery('#EbeneAuswahl'),
          xavManager.jQuery('#ElementAuswahl'),
          xavManager.jQuery('#MaterialAuswahl'),
          xavManager.jQuery('#SetArtikelAuswahl'),
          xavManager.jQuery('#GriffArtikelAuswahl')],
           constanten
          );
        });
 </script>
```

After i call the page, the last script is executed and throws the exception.

[The Structure of the Project looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjGKN.jpg)

So the three Classes are in three Files and two of them in the same libori, the other one in another.

**EDIT Part2:**

After I have restarted my pc this error message disappears ...
But another Error in some js-File appears....

> Syntax Error **ONLY IN JS-FILE**
>   He can't compile one File

```
class SelectionRules extends ValidationRules {

   protected _getNewTimedOutObject():         ValidationRules_TimeoutItem_Calculate|SelectionRules_TimeoutItem_Calculate {
       return new SelectionRules_TimeoutItem_Calculate();
   }
}

class SelectionRules_TimeoutItem_Calculate extends     ValidationRules_TimeoutItem_Calculate {
   public liElement: HTMLElement;
}

class ValidationRules_TimeoutItem_Calculate {
   public Timeout: number;
   public Setting: Widget_ConfiguratorBase_Object_Setting;
   public SearchString: string;
   public ErrorText: string;
   public Value: string = "";
   public DataElement: Widget_Article_Setting;
   public ContainerEntryIndex: number;
}
```

> Is it because these Part? 
>   ValidationRules_TimeoutItem_Calculate|SelectionRules_TimeoutItem_Calculate

But why does these lines work with TypeScript 1.4?

Comment: Maybe the error is somewhere else but i don't understand why this error occurs....
The other question is: Why did this error came after i changed the version?
With 1.4 everything is fine ....

Comment: Is this a compilation error? I think you should post more code, the code you posted is working and compiles in typescript playground. The only thing that comes to my mind is that you have a problem with `export` and your classes are no longer available outside where they are defined

Comment: I hope the edit will help

Comment: Edit part2 ---> just more confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tons of hours i got it....

> After you upgraded TypeScript, **restart Visual-Studio!**
>   If you work with ECMA6 and you Double Typed like Parameter/Functions like ValidationRules_TimeoutItem_Calculate|SelectionRules_TimeoutItem_Calculate you need to Change the solution-options back to **ECMA5**
>   same issue with new generated Classes! --> back to **ECMA5** it will work
>   after compile these everything work